# Get browser URL in JSF 1.2 bean

Tags: jsf

I'm using Tuckey URL rewriter on my site so (for example) the URL www.test.com/faces/dynamicForm.jsp appears to the user as www.test.com/a/b/c/form.html

In my bean, how to I access the URL the user is seeing in their browser, in this case: www.test.com/a/b/c/form.html

Answer (score 0):

You can get the [HttpServletRequest](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) from [javax.faces.context.ExternalContext](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/j2ee/javaserverfaces/1.1_01/docs/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html).

From which you can call [getRequestURL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURL%28%29) method.

```
HttpServletRequest request = (
HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
String url = request.getRequestURL()
```